# How do I left-align this equation?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations, split

I wrote an equation in LaTeX, and it is centered. How can I left align it but without losing the split? (I still want the equal signs one under each other).

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
a &=(3+6+9+12+...+147)+1125\\
&=3 \cdot (1+2+3+4+...+49)+1125\\
&=3 \cdot \displaystyle\frac{49 \cdot 50}{2} + 1125=49 \cdot 75 + 1125\\
&=3675 + 1125\\
&=4900\\
&=70^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{a} = \sqrt{70^2}=70 \end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: Juste celle-ci à gauche, ou toutes vos équations?

Comment: Does the `fleqn` option to the documentclass help?

Comment: You can replace `\begin{equation*}\begin{split}` with `\begin{flalign*}` and add `&` before every `\\ ` as a quick fix. Although I'd also change some other aspects of your euation, such as multiple equal signs on some lines, which makes things messy IMO. Also, `...` should be replace with `\ldots`.

Comment: For an occasional left-aligned equation , the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` does the job.

Comment: The main question is: why should the display be left aligned?

Answer (score 1):

I find no reason for this display to be flush left. Anyway…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The following display is left aligned. I don't know why it should be
treated differently from the other displays, but here it is anyhow.
\begin{flushleft}
$\begin{aligned}
a &=(3+6+9+12+\dots+147)+1125\\
  &=3 \cdot (1+2+3+4+\dots+49)+1125\\
  &=3 \cdot \frac{49 \cdot 50}{2} + 1125=49 \cdot 75 + 1125\\
  &=3675 + 1125\\
  &=4900\\
  &=70^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{a} = \sqrt{70^2}=70
\end{aligned}$
\end{flushleft}
Note that dots should be specified with \verb|\dots|, not with
three periods and that \verb|\displaystyle| is not needed; there
is \verb|\dfrac|, if needed (not here).

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you could use `\parbox` with the width set to 0 to accomplish this.

```
\noindent Previous line.

\noindent\parbox{0mm}{
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
a &=(3+6+9+12+...+147)+1125\\
&=3 \cdot (1+2+3+4+...+49)+1125\\
&=3 \cdot \displaystyle\frac{49 \cdot 50}{2} + 1125=49 \cdot 75 + 
1125\\
&=3675 + 1125\\
&=4900\\
&=70^2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{a} = \sqrt{70^2}=70 \end{split}
\end{equation*}
}

\noindent Next line.
```

[image]